# ModelMultipleChoiceField - cleaned_data have no value

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms, choicefield

I want to make simple blog with posts and tags, but i have a problem with adding tags from ModelMultipleChoiceField... after calling .is_valid(), cleaned_data should have selected tags but instead it is None.

```
print(form.cleaned_data)
```

returns:

```
{'description': u'xyz', 'title': u'xyz', 'haslo': u'', 'tags': None}
```

I have tried to change it to simple ChoiceField with initial choices from table but with same result.

---

### **My models:**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    nazwa = models.CharField(max_length=24)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwa

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nazwa

class Post(models.Model):
    tytul = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    skrocona_tresc = models.CharField(max_length=350, blank=True)
    tresc = models.TextField(blank=True)
    haslo = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=True)
    data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    id_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

---

### **Form:**

```
class PostAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),required=False)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),required=False)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),required=False)
    tags = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Tag.objects.all(), required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'title',
            'password',
            'description',
            'tags'
        ]
```

---

### **and view:**

```
    def add_post(request):
    forma_PA = PostAddForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.is_ajax():
        if forma_PA.is_valid():
            post = forma_PA.save(commit=False)
            post.tresc = request.POST.get('html')
            post = Post(tytul=forma_PA.cleaned_data.get('title'),
                        id_user_id=request.user.id,
                        skrocona_tresc=forma_PA.cleaned_data.get('description'),
                        tresc=request.POST.get('html'),
                        haslo=forma_PA.cleaned_data.get('password'),
                        )
            post.save()
            tagi = forma_PA.cleaned_data['tags']
            print(forma_PA.cleaned_data)
            if(tagi):
                post.tags.add(tagi)
    context = {
        'form': forma_PA
    }
    return render(request, 'Blog/add_post.html', context)
```

i am just starting with Django ;/

Comment: Even simple HTML form and pulling data from request.POST is not working ... What is going on with this thing ?

Comment: Anyone ? Something ?